# Observing or getting notified of change in battery state for watchOS

Tags: observable, key-value-observing, battery, watchos-4

Is there any way to be notified of changes in battery state in real time without periodically checking for the state?

I tried finding an equivalent to `UIDevice.UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification` available on iOS, but `WKInterfaceDevice` for watchOS doesn't seem to offer this Notification.

Even though the [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html) specifies that classes in `UIKit` do not support KVO, and it is probably the same deal with `WatchKit`, I still tried registering an observer on `WKInterfaceDevice.current().batteryState` as follow, but it doesn't notify of changes

```
    WKInterfaceDevice.current().isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
    batteryObserver = WKInterfaceDevice.current().observe(\.batteryState) {
        [weak self] _, _ in self?.onBatteryStateChange()
    }
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this without polling for the state periodically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to make a custom notification from a singleton object that polls the battery state and level at regular intervals. If ever you have a better solution please share it with me, I'm not so fond of the polling part.

[Here is the sample code for this](https://gist.github.com/Gevrai/7093ba9074350e32c191392537388e49)